# How to get rid of the horizontal scroll in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I needed to add a overflow-y to accommodate draggable elements. But now when I drag items the area where they reside is adding having a horizontal scroll.

[Demo](http://www.6ft.me/uzCs3Et) with scroll.
[Demo](http://www.6ft.me/ux6ysu) that works properly.

Drag item from the left column to the right field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [scroll](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#scroll) option to false on your draggables when you create them.  That should prevent them from auto scrolling the container

```
    $("#myDraggable").draggable({
        scroll : false,
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried that, for some reason it did not work. Perhaps I can add this to the parent <td> as well...